# How can i set my image to the bottom of the screen in android using xml code

Tags: android

hi i have displayed a PNG image on screen in android by using XML code:

android:src="@drawable/grass"

but it is showing image at top of the screen ,now i want that image at bottom of the screen.

Comment: put your layout code here please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make sure your layout file is taking full of your screen by setting match_parent or fill_parent for both layout_height and layout_width.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/grass"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/grass"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

      </RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT

Programmatically

```
ImageView pic;    

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic);
pic.setLayoutParams(param);
```

Comment: how can i declare this programatically?